# Install error when bazel is built for syntaxnet

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, syntaxnet

I am trying to run Syntaxnet on my computer but got stuck at the part of bazel installation.
When i executed "bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...", all test targets were skipped.
The error codes are as below.
[image: screenhot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like zlib is missing. On Ubuntu just:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

and then retry installation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried as you told and the same errors occurred. I wonder if my Pc is too slow, is it possible to throw the errors above? My pc takes almost an hour to execute "bazel test syntaxnet/... util/utf8/.... Is it normal?

Comment: 1 hour seem a bit long to me. I had also some issues when compiling without limiting resources, I always got some unspecific gcc errors (but no error about missing references). I used "--local_resources 2048,1.0,1.0 -f 1" then it worked, but with that options it is realy slow, approx. 0.5 days.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you missed a step for the bazel's installation; try this:

sudo apt-get install pkg-config zip g++ zlib1g-dev unzip

Comment: Thanks for  your concern. I have tried the command you told me but my computer says i have got the newest version of package installed.